# Set WebApi 2 routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm fairly new to WepApi2 and creating restfull webservice, but I get the hang of most of it.

Recently, I started developing a new WebApi2 where I encounter that some of my queries required some unesacapable characters, specially the slash and inverted slash ones.

I read several tutorials and questions here about the matter, but none would suffice me, so I ended up to setting my api queries like this

```
http://host/controler/action/?param1=x&param2=y
```

Everything works perfect. I had to setup the `ActionName` and `Route` attributes to my action, no problem there, but once I tried the old way of query

```
http://host/controller/action/x/y
```

I would always get a `No action was found on the controller 'Controller' that matches the request.`

Here's my routes configuration

```
// Web API configuration and services
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            // Web API routes
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "HelloWorld", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Config1",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "action", param2 = RouteParameter.Optional, param3 = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Config2",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
                defaults: new { controller = "action", param3 = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

You may notice I have 2 configurations. Well, the first is to classify the action under a controller, as so, in the future, can add more controllers with specific actions, instead of having a huge list of controllers with an specific action, but the second approach is what the client wants.

So, is there a way to have both ways working together??

Edit: My bad, I forgot to show how my controller and actions where setup

```
public class ControllerController : WebApiController
    {
        [Route("Controller/action1/")]
        [ActionName("action1")]
        [HttpGet()]
        public Object action1(string param1, string param2)
        {
            // do action actions code
            return result;
        }
```

As you can see, besides setting the route in the config, I'm also setting the action routing attribute, but I wasn't aware I could set more than 1 Route attribute. Will try that and report back!

Comment: I would recommend changing to Attribute based routing instead of string routing in this case.  Attribute routing allows you to assign rules in your controller class, rather than in a separate route config based on string matches, and is much more robust when dealing with route combinations.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention it, please, see my edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) instead:

```
// in your startup configuration:

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

// and your controller:

[RoutePrefix("foo")]
public class FooController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("bar/{param1}/{param2}")]
    [Route("bar")
    public IHttpActionResult GetBar(string param1, string param2)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, so I can set it both ways? I did already had attribute routing, please, see my edit, but I wasn't aware it supported more than 1 setup