# Setup mvc routing for parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was asked to setup the routing so the next route works

```
https://<server>/<weapp>/<paramater>
```

I already had the default controller and action working, this route works as intended

```
https://<server>/<weapp>/?param1=<paramater>
```

But my clients want me to get rid of the `?param1=` and that it works as intended by only setting the parameter at the end of the url

I had seen this work, but I just can't find how to configure nor why which keywords to search it. My google fu is weak on this one

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+api+routing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: already looked through the first 5 answers of the search yesterday and none resolved my question.

Comment: The [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029910/set-webapi-2-routes) you accepted yesterday already answers this question.

Comment: Actually, my bad, that one was for webapi, this one is for mvc, though both uses the base for routing, there can be differences, and I had already found my solution, after lurking on some more obscure google fu findings

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some more lurking on more obscure google fu findings, I finally find my answer

I did had already setup a route that, in my mind, should suffice my client needs

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Shortener",
                url: "{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "<controller>", action = "<action>", id = UrlParameter.Optional }//new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But I was always setting up new route maps after the ones I had. This little bit I found [in this article](http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/attribute-routing-vs-convention-routing/) gave some new light that previous articles I read about the matter never mentioned, not even MSDN

> One thing to keep in mind when designing your routes is that the order
>   in which the routes are added to the table matters. The routing engine
>   will take the first route that matches the supplied URL and attempt to
>   use the route values in that route. Therefore, less common or more
>   specialized routes should be added to the table first, while more
>   general routes should be added later on.

So, after setting my route config at the top of all the other routes configs, the url

```
https://<server>/<weapp>/<paramater>
```

worked like a charm!

Hope this helps anyone else!